# How to save xml comments like <!--pagebreak--> when converting dita file to docx (with com.elovirta.ooxml v.1.4)

Tags: xslt, openxml, docx, dita, dita-ot

I use: Dita open toolkit 3.7.4, plugin com.elovirta.ooxml, java 17.
I have such dita file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="_1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <body>
        <p>First</p>
        <!--pagebreak-->
        <p>Second</p>
        <p>Third</p>
    </body>
</topic>
```

Under standard conditions, the comment (<!--pagebreak-->) disappears during conversion.

I have added a handler file pagebreaks.xsl with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and added a link to it in document.xsl:

```
...  
<xsl:import href="pagebreaks.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="document.utils.xsl"/>
...
```

However, that doesn't work either.

Tell me how to save xml comments during conversion in docx file?

It is expected that the output is something like this document.xml content in a docx file

```
...
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="BodyText"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>First</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <!--pagebreak-->
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="BodyText"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Second</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="BodyText"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Third</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
...
```

Comment: It's not enough to have a template that copies comments. You also need to apply it to the comments you want to copy. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: If all else fails you could preprocess your input to turn the comments into something that does survive the transformation, and the postprocess the result to turn it back into comments.

Comment: Thanks. I thought in this direction, but I would like to do it using the plugin.

Comment: If you look in the "com.elovirta.ooxml/docx/word/document.topic.xsl" XSLT stylesheet it has an xsl template which looks like this:
 <xsl:template match="\*[contains(@class, ' topic/body ')]" name="body">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="\*"/>
</xsl:template>
so it only applies templates on "\*" meaning child elements of the body, this is why it no longer calls your template which matches the comment. Probably you can change that to:

 <xsl:apply-templates select="\* | comment()"/>

But I really do not understand the use case, if inside the docx you end up with that XML comment, then what?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I need a comment for post-processing, in certain cases I need to rotate the sheet.

Comment: Unfortunately, after making changes to document.topic.xsl, comments still disappear.